# Java security issue while downloading gradle plugins in ubuntu

Tags: java, ssl, gradle, ssl-certificate, gradle-plugin

Our gradle build is using SVN tools plugin and works without problem on windows.The part of build script using build problem looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "at.bxm.gradleplugins:gradle-svntools-plugin:2.2.1"
    }
}
apply plugin: "at.bxm.svntools"
```

I tried to run the same build on ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but I got this error message:

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve at.bxm.gradleplugins:gradle-svntools-plugin:2.2.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve at.bxm.gradleplugins:gradle-svntools-plugin:2.2.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/at/bxm/gradleplugins/gradle-svntools-plugin/2.2.1/gradle-svntools-plugin-2.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/at/bxm/gradleplugins/gradle-svntools-plugin/2.2.1/gradle-svntools-plugin-2.2.1.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

I am using the same version of Java and Gradle on both machine. StackTrace is showing that there is some problem with SSL-certificates. What should I do to be able to use gradle plugins repository in my script?

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/at/bxm/gradleplugins/gradle-svntools-plugin/2.2.1/gradle-svntools-plugin-2.2.1.pom'.
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:331)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:321)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
        ... 153 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:148)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:126)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:94)
        ... 169 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        ... 184 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        ... 184 more
```

Comment: if you are using openjdk, try using oracle jdk. openjdk does not come with full ca-certs.

Comment: Thanks @gagansingh .First I had  OpenJDK 10 but I removed it and installed oracle jdk 8 but I still am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cacerts. It is not enough to remove OpenJDK and install oracle JDK8. You should update/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts (remove cacerts and copy new on from {ORACLE_JDK_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts). 
First time I did that I run

```
update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

after but then it didn't work so the next time I copied certificates again without running update-ca-certificates --fresh and it worked